# Jetty How can I add a servlet filter using IOC xml ? The Servlet is already configured using addServlet

Tags: jetty, inversion-of-control

Jetty How can I add a servlet filter using IOC xml ? 
The Servlet/ServletContextHandler is already configured using addServlet . How can I add a Filter to this Servlet